# Using aftermath in place of after-effect

Tags: word-usage

Aftermath is defined as follows in the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aftermath):

> > **aftermath NOUN** 1The consequences or after-effects of a significant unpleasant event.

Does it mean we can use it as the replacement of **"after-effect"**? For example, if my sentence is as follows:

> > The **after-effects** of the world war will be dreadful for the entire world.

Can I write it as follows:

> > The **aftermath** of the world war will be dreadful for the entire world.

I checked the example sentences given on the Oxford page. All these examples used the following phrase: **"In the aftermath of"**. But if "aftermath" is used in such a way then the following definition from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aftermath) looks more precise:

> > **aftermath** **Noun** the period that follows an unpleasant event or accident, and the effects that it causes:

Comment: '_Aftermath_' is mostly used to signify a **major** or **significant** event, caused as a consequence of another event. Although similar, '_after-effect_' could also imply **small** or **minor** consequences to an event.

Answer (score 2):

Aftermath refers to the immediate period following some event. Its origin according to the SOED is "after-mowing" that is the first growth of grass that appears after the mower has finished. So you can say "in the aftermath of the Second World War, food supplies were restricted". It would sound odd, however, to refer to the collapse of the Warsaw Pact bloc in 1989 as part of the aftermath of that war even though that collapse might be argued to be an after-effect of the war.

It is a matter of judgement how long after an event aftermath is still appropriate, but after-effects begin immediately and can go on indefinitely.